# Run Windows 7 partition as virtual machine in Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I have a dual-boot setup with Ubuntu Linux and Windows 7. Is it possible, in any way, to have a virtual machine to run from the Windows 7 partition, when I'm running Ubuntu on the machine?

The scenario would be: I boot into Ubuntu when I start my computer, and then I can run a virtual machine with my Windows 7 installation.

Comment: Similar question on Ask Ubuntu that was asked three days ago, but not yet answered: [Virtual machine using natively installed windows](http://askubuntu.com/questions/120936/virtual-machine-using-natively-installed-windows)

Comment: Detailed instructions: http://www.theunixtips.com/virtualbox-use-raw-disk-to-load-windows-under-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vmware workstation you have ability to create VM from a real system. I did that before and now this system is working in the vmware player. However, this is not a partition, but the big file with system. I don't think that this even possible, because virtualized systems can use only their own hardware components (that is virtualized) and when you'll change them in real system (when you launching windows in ubuntu) - you won't be able to login back to the real system. Because registry of the windows system will have modified drivers for hardware devices (that can be used in vm).

Comment: Good point.
But in VM, does it create a big file out of your File System, or can you run a VM off a complete, regular HDD?

Comment: I don't know. Creation of the file system image at the same file system - maybe not so trivial task. I have created vm file at the different partition.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the big file with system"?

Comment: Also, have you found a comprehensive tutorial online that explains how to do this?

Comment: He means the image file that Workstation makes as a virtual HDD.